# How can i make a volume slider in unity work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, volume

So I'm fairly new to unity, and I've been working on a knockoff version of The Worlds Hardest Game. I've made an options menu with just a volume slider, but I can't seem to get the slider to do anything. I wrote the code, but I don't understand why nothing happens. I also can't figure out how to save the data of the slider after changing to another scene (Like the main menu)  Here's some code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class VolumeSlider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer mixer;



    public void SetVolumeLevel(float sliderValue)
    {
        mixer.SetFloat("musicVol", Mathf.Log10 (sliderValue));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create the slider**

In the hierarchy select Create > UI > Slider to create a UI Slider for your volume control

Select the Slider object and set the Min Value to 0.0001 (the logarithmic conversion will not work correctly at zero)

Set the Value to 1

[image]

**Expose the Audio Mixer Group volume to scripting.**

Select the Audio Mixer Group that you want to control with the slider.

In the inspector, under attenuation, right click on the volume label and select Expose ‘Volume (of Music)’ to script.

[image]

In the Audio Mixer Panel, select the Exposed Parameters dropdown and give the, now exposed, volume parameter a name. e.g. “MusicVol”. You’ll need to use the parameter name given here when accessing it from a script.

[image]

**Connect the slider with a script**

Add a new C Sharp script to the slider object called SetVolume or similar.

Open it for editing and type, or paste, the following script:
Save the script and return to Unity.

Use circle select to connect the mixer reference variable to the Mixer that contains the exposed parameter.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class SetVolume : MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioMixer mixer;

    public void SetLevel (float sliderValue)
    {
       mixer.SetFloat("MusicVol", Mathf.Log10(sliderValue) * 20);
    }
}
```

To read the rest of the article, refer to the following link :

[The right way to make a volume slider in Unity (using logarithmic conversion)](https://gamedevbeginner.com/the-right-way-to-make-a-volume-slider-in-unity-using-logarithmic-conversion/)

Comment: link-only answers can become invalid, and thus are not considered proper answers. Consider editing your question to add at least a relevant part or the principle of the solution.

Comment: thanks for review my post . i've working on editing this post

Comment: After all it become a quite nice answer ;)

Comment: you get mine, indeed a nice answer now!

Comment: i appreciate it so much